# Edit doesn't work on file upload

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new in Laravel and got into trouble when began to work with real files, not fakers.
What I am trying to do is:
I have store function- putting images from pc into my site.
But all crashes when I am trying to make edit- it doesn't work on images: for that I am using Submit function
My PhotoController:

```
public function create()
{
  $categories = Category::all();
  return view('photo.create', compact('photo','categories'));
}
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
   'title' => 'required|min:3',
   'image_url'=> 'required',
   'category_id' => 'required',
    ]);

     $photo = new Photo;
     if ($request->hasFile('image_url')) {
                     $file = $request->file('image_url');

                    $fileName = $request->image_url->store('');
                    $photo->image_url =  $fileName;
                 }

     $photo->title = $request->input('title');

     $photo->description = $request->input('description');
     $photo->category_id = $request->input('category_id');
     $photo->save();

     $request->session()->flash('create', $request->title. "Sekmingai sukurta");
     $path = $request->image_url->store('public');
     return redirect()->route('photos.index');

}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    return view('photos.index', compact('photo'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
  $photo = Photo::find($id );
  $categories = Category::all();

    return view('photo.edit', compact('photo', 'categories'));
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function submit(Request $request, $id)
{

  $photo = Photo::find($id);

  $photo->title = $request->input('title');
  $photo = new Photo;
  if ($request->hasFile('image_url')) {
                  $file = $request->file('image_url');

                 $fileName = $request->image_url->store('');
                 $photo->image_url =  $fileName;
              }

  $photo->description = $request->input('description');
  $photo->category_id = $request->input('category_id');

  $photo->update();

  $request->session()->flash('update', $request->title. "Sekmingai papildyta");
  $path = $request->image_url->store('public');
  return redirect()->route('photo.edit', $photo->id);

}
```

When I am trying to edit file and upload new photo- I am getting error:

> "Call to a member function store() on string"

And it is showing that error is in this line:

```
$path = $request->image_url->store('public');
```

Anybody could suggest? Thank you

Comment: Try it like this : `$path = $request->file('image_url')->store('public');` !!

Comment: I have tried: then I am getting error: "Call to a member function store() on null"

Comment: Yes in case you didn't send the file So you should add it in the if statment `if($request->hasFile('image_url'))` to be sure that there is a file ;)

Comment: thank you for help, but I have if:

Comment: if ($request->hasFile('image_url')) {
                  $file = $request->file('image_url');

                 $fileName = $request->image_url->store('');
                 $photo->image_url =  $fileName;
              }

Comment: Yes i know that's why i said you shoud add `$path = $request->file('image_url')->store('public');` in the if statment because there is cases that you will not upload a file for example and it will cause you a problem !!

Comment: my if looks like this now:if ($request->hasFile('image_url')) {
                      $file = $request->file('image_url');

                     $path = $request->file('image_url')->store('public');
                     $photo->image_url =  $fileName;
                  }

Comment: and after: $photo->description = $request->input('description');
      $photo->category_id = $request->input('category_id');

      $photo->update();

      $request->session()->flash('update', $request->title. "Sekmingai papildyta");
      $path = $request->image_url->store('public');
      return redirect()->route('photo.edit', $photo->id);

Comment: shows error "Call to a member function store() on string". if i delete path after update- it stops finding update page at all

Comment: What do you mean by : it stops finding update page at all

Comment: http://manufaktura.app/photos//edit  appears and it shows "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

Comment: i think because you have double // no ??

Comment: yes, but from where it came from

Comment: I think from your form action !!

Comment: or your route is not well formated `'photo.edit'`